# How to recreate the sauce in McDonald's 1955 Burger?

Tags: hamburgers, restaurant-mimicry, barbecue-sauce

For a few weeks, my local McDonalds was selling a burger called the "1955 Burger", which had a really delicious sauce with lots of other things mixed in. I tried buying various BBQ sauces in the stores, but none had a similar taste.

What kind of BBQ sauce can I buy that will be close to what McDonalds uses? What other ingredients did McDonalds mix into the BBQ sauce?

Comment: What does the sauce taste like? Is it sweet and/or vinegary? Does it taste of mustard or molasses? Any relation to the sauce they show in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcu4Bj3xEyI&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=McDonald%27sCanada ?

Comment: @derobert Did a search on the burger and the sauce was described as a smoky BBQ sauce.

Comment: @Cindy that's so common I don't think it really helps much. One other place I saw described it as more creamy than a normal BBQ sauce (what their normal is, who knows). Which makes me wonder if it isn't something like that sauce McDonald's has in the video, but maybe with smoked paprika. Of course, neither of us have tasted it... OP needs to tell us, since he/she has tasted it.

Comment: @derobert Agree, it's not much help. In the pictures I saw, it looked like a regular BBQ sauce. But it may be something totally foreign to us. Fast food (or food in general) in other countries can differ greatly from what we are familiar with.

Comment: @derobert I believe the BBQ sauce itself is similar to that distributed with chicken nugget meals. All I can say to describe it is it is much stronger in flavor that the BBQ sauces I have bought in the store and towards the sweet side. Every sauce I've bought in stores disappointed me, not coming anywhere close to the same flavor. But the 1995 Burger also had various vegetables mixed into the sauce.

Comment: The 1955 burger has a similar sauce to the one used in the Chicken Maharaja Mac burger served in India.

Comment: @Mike That's useful to know, but it would be more helpful to know how to duplicate the flavor profile (the OP may not be able to travel to India regularly to get that sauce, for example)